# Using ROW_NUMBER() in nested sqlite3 query with sqlalchemy causes sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Upon executing the following python function to run a sql query to a sqlite3 database, I receive a `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

***python function with query text***

```
def total_docs():
"total documents"
   import db
   conn, cursor = db.opendb()
   cursor.execute('''
   SELECT COUNT(a.custId) 
   FROM (
   SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
      PARTITION BY custId, invoiceId ORDER BY entryDate DESC
    ) latest_rank , custId, customer, page, invoiceDate
   FROM 
   transactions
   ) a 
   WHERE latest_rank = 1
   ''')
   return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Is there something about how `execute()` runs this query or the actual query that's not compliant with using sqlalchemy to execute SQL. The query works as expected in a DB client(Dbeaver) and so I'm a little stomped as to why this isn't working.

Comment: You're probably using an old version of sqlite that doesn't support window functions. Make sure you're using 3.25 or newer.

Comment: @Shawn that was it! Thanks.